# How to set vertical space in table and figure as picture follows?

Tags: spacing, captions

[image]

How to set vertical space as picture above? I only can set for all caption and I can't set for only "figure" caption and "table" caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4 cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{24pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{24pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{18pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{18pt}
\begin{document}
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{Figure BlaBlaBla}
    \end{figure}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Table BlaBlaBla}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `caption`, you can set caption skips for individual environments. Then, set both lengths `\intextsep` and `\textfloatsep` to 24pt (see the bottom screenshot)

[image]

If the slight extra space after a `figure`'s caption bothers you, just remove comments from the following lines

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\vspace{-2pt}}
```

A screenshot from the package layout` page 28:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4 cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Added
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[figure]{skip=18pt, position=bottom}
    \captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt, position=top}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
%     \AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\vspace{-2pt}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\intextsep}{24pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{24pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{Figure BlaBlaBla}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Table BlaBlaBla}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{document}
```